# Required Derby DataSource property databaseName not set

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, derby, persistence.xml

After unsuccessfully trying to switch to Postgresql from Derby using a Glassfish4 server, I wanted to switch back to my previous Derby based web app. But when I tried to deploy my app the following error appeared:

```
[2014-10-20T23:13:36.297+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1413839616297] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Required Derby DataSource property databaseName not set.
Error Code: 0
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Required Derby DataSource property databaseName not set.
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connectInternal(DatasourceAccessor.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.connectInternal(DatabaseAccessor.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connect(DatasourceAccessor.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ConnectionPool.buildConnection(ConnectionPool.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ExternalConnectionPool.startUp(ExternalConnectionPool.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.connect(ServerSession.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:748)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:681)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:358)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:922)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:431)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:396)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:165)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:181)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Required Derby DataSource property databaseName not set.
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:132)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Required Derby DataSource property databaseName not set.
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:146)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: Required Derby DataSource property databaseName not set.
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:103)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1512)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:944)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: Required Derby DataSource property databaseName not set.
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:98)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: Required Derby DataSource property databaseName not set.
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: Required Derby DataSource property databaseName not set.
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:129)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Required Derby DataSource property databaseName not set.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:117)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Required Derby DataSource property databaseName not set.
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.checkDatabaseName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl40.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource.getConnectionX(Unknown Source)
    ... 98 more
]]
```

This is my persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="scuolaTennisNicolaPU"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.storassa.javaee.scuolatennisnicola.Player</class>
        <class>com.storassa.javaee.scuolatennisnicola.News</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="DERBY" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/tiebreak;create=true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="APP" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="APP" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
            <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is the same file I used before, as I'm using git and I checked out all the modifications I did in the latter. Which could be the issue?

---

UPDATE

I think I found where the property databaseName is missing. It is the domain.xml file for Glassfish configuration, that is not under git. This is the jdbc-connection-pool part

```
<jdbc-connection-pool is-isolation-level-guaranteed="false" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" name="DerbyPool">
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="DERBY" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/tiebreak;create=true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="APP" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="APP" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
            <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="true" />

</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

The problem now is to understand which value this property should take. I didn't find any hints googling here and there.

---

UPDATE 2

I tried to insert

with the following result

```
remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: The connection was refused because the database sun-appserv-samples was not fou
```

nd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my issue.
The sun-appserv-samples directory was not under workspace/, but under the main worspace directory. Coping the whole directory under the project one (and restarting glassfish to avoid security issues) solved my problem